# Ruby RPG combat mechanics

Tags: ruby

I posted the other day about a Zork-like RPG written in Ruby that I'm working on. However, I can't get the combat mechanics and level-up system to work out. Basically, what I want is a Zork-like world interface, i.e. a bit of text describing your surroundings. That's not a problem.

The problem is, I'd like to have a way to generate creatures, and make it optional whether you fight them or not. For example, if you type something like "fight cow," you'd start hitting the cow with whatever weapon you had available, and get xp or an item or something when you kill it. Or you could look at it, or try to pick it up, or just leave it alone. Any ideas about how I could make this work?

Comment: Oh, by the way, I'm fairly new to Ruby, so word your answers as simply as possible please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an impossibly broad question.

Here are some potential resources:

- http://www.bitwisemag.com/2/Adventures-In-Ruby (and its following parts).
- http://lanyrd.com/2010/scotrug-may/symk/
- http://alltom.com/pages/room
- http://www.dzone.com/snippets/slightly-better-ruby-text

And so on.

Good SO questions will have specific problems. Adventure game mechanics can be implemented in any number of ways; it's not at all clear what issue(s) you're actually having.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Sorry my question wasn't more precise, I wasn't exactly sure where to start.